# Substitute a part of string (ignoring special characters)

Tags: python, string, replace

Suppose that I have a list of strings, and I want to substitute different parts of it by `re.sub`. My problem is that sometimes this substitution contains special characters inside so this function can't properly match the structure. One example:

```
import re

txt = 'May enbd company Ltd (Pty) Ltd, formerly known as apple shop Ltd., is a full service firm which is engaged in the sale and servicing of motor vehicles.'

re.sub('May enbd company Ltd (Pty) Ltd', 'PC (Pty) Ltd', txt)
```

Here the issue is coming from `(` and `)`, but the other forms may happen that I'm not aware of it now. So I want to totally ignore these special characters inside and replace them with my preferred strings. In this case, it means:

```
 'PC (Pty) Ltd, formerly known as apple shop Ltd., is a full-service firm which is engaged in the sale and servicing of motor vehicles.'
```

Comment: `re.sub('May enbd company Ltd \(Pty\) Ltd', 'PC (Pty) Ltd', txt)`

Comment: @SaSkY this fixes just this case but is not inclusive of all other cases that may happen. As mentioned, there is a long list of strings and patterns I have to match and replace, so many exceptions may happen inside, and I want to ignore all possible cases.

Comment: If you don't need the additional regex functionality you could just use the string method `replace`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Good solution. Please add this as an answer.

Comment: By the way: If you have to use regular expressions for some reason, there is the `re.escape` function to automatically escape special regex characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no special functionality of regular expressions is needed, this can be done easier with the [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method:

```
txt = 'May enbd company Ltd (Pty) Ltd, formerly known as apple shop Ltd., is a full service firm which is engaged in the sale and servicing of motor vehicles.'

result = txt.replace('May enbd company Ltd (Pty) Ltd', 'PC (Pty) Ltd')
```